# Panel не получается настроить адаптацию при открытие программы на весь экран

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть панель, по типу WrapPanel, при изменение ширины элементы растягиваются и когда появляется доступное место с другой строки на доступное место переносится элемент. Это хорошо работает при изменение размера за края приложения и если я растяну на большую часть экрана и нажму кнопку развернуть на весь экран, то все отступы сохраняются
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если окно приложения будет размером меньше чем на пол экрана и я нажму кнопку развернуть на весь экран, то элементы теряют правильные отступы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видно что у строк отступы не ровные
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите из за чего при разворачивание на весь экран теряются отступы, как можно исправить это еще не разобрался.

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows;

namespace Wpap_Test
{
    public class FillingPanel : Panel
    {
        // Этап подсчета занимаемого места
        protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
        {
            double width = 0, maxWidth = 0, y = 0, nextY = 0;
            foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
            {
                // Запрашиваем измерение желаемого размера
                child.Measure(availableSize);
                // Если элемент помещается в текущую строку
                if (width + child.DesiredSize.Width <= availableSize.Width)
                { 
                    // увеличиваем ширину текущей строки
                    width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
                }
                // иначе
                else
                {
                    // предполагаем размещение элемента в следующей строке
                    width = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    y = nextY;
                }
                // Запоминаем максимальную потребную ширину
                if (width > maxWidth)
                    maxWidth = width;
                // и высоту панели
                if (y + child.DesiredSize.Height > nextY)
                    nextY = y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
            }
            return new Size(maxWidth, nextY);
        }

        // Этап размещения элементов
        protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
        {
            double y = 0, nextY = 0, width = 0;
            // Коллекция, содержащая элементы текущей строки
            var line = new List<FrameworkElement>();
            foreach (FrameworkElement child in Children)
            {
                // Если элемент уместится в текущей строке
                if (width + child.DesiredSize.Width <= finalSize.Width)
                {
                   
                    // Подсчитываем потребную ширину строки
                    width += child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    // Подсчитываем смещение по вертикали следущей строки
                    if (y + child.DesiredSize.Height > nextY)
                        nextY = y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
                    if (width + child.DesiredSize.Width >= finalSize.Width)
                        //Задаем Margin для последнего элемента строки
                        child.Margin = new Thickness(7, 7, 7, 0);
                    else
                        //Задаем Margin для элемента строки
                        child.Margin = new Thickness(7, 7, 0, 0);
                    // Помещаем его в список элементов
                    line.Add(child);
                }
                // иначе
                else
                {
                    // Размещаем строку
                    ArrangeLine(line, finalSize.Width, y, nextY - y);
                    // Элементы следующей строки
                    line = new List<FrameworkElement> { child };
                    width = child.DesiredSize.Width;
                    y = nextY;
                    nextY = y + child.DesiredSize.Height;
                    //Задаем Margin для первого элемента новой строки
                    child.Margin = new Thickness(7, 7, 0, 0);
                }
            }
            //Задаем Margin для последнего элемента панели
            line.Last().Margin = new Thickness(7, 7, 7, 0);
            // Последняя строка
            ArrangeLine(line, finalSize.Width, y, nextY - y);
            return finalSize;
        }

        private void ArrangeLine(List<FrameworkElement> line, double lineWidth, double y, double lineHeight)
        {
            // Потребная ширина строки
            double width = line.Sum(fe => fe.DesiredSize.Width);
            // Делим оставшуюся часть длины строки на все элементы
            double delta = (lineWidth - width) / line.Count;
            // Смещение элемента внутри строки
            double x = 0;
            foreach (var fe in line)
            {
                // Вычисляем ширину текущего элемента
                double curWidth = fe.DesiredSize.Width + delta;
                // Размещаем элемент
                fe.Arrange(new Rect(x, y, curWidth, lineHeight));
                // Вычисляем смещение следующего
                x += curWidth;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Wpf

```
<Window x:Class="Wpap_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Wpap_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="550" Width="745" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ItemMarginWrapPanel}">
            <Setter  Property="ItemMargin" Value="7" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid Margin="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Border Margin="14 20 14 0" CornerRadius="6" Height="40" Background="Gray">
                <TextBlock Margin="20 0 0 0" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center">Title</TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <local:FillingPanel Background="#F1F1F1F1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="0 14 0 0" >
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1E69B9B"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1653232"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1421D1D"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1FF2222"></Border>
                <Border x:Name="five" Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F10D004E"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F15135DE"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1E69B9B"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1653232"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1421D1D"></Border>
                <Border x:Name="ten" Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F1FF2222"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F10D004E"></Border>
                <Border Height="100" CornerRadius="6" MinWidth="351" Background="#F15135DE"></Border>
            </local:FillingPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Проблема главным образом в Margin, который вы выставляете при Arrange. Если хотите отступ, то меняйте Rect, который передаёте в Arrange у элемента. А выставление Margin уберите. Долго объяснять, но в кратце Margin влияет на размер рассчитываемый (DesiredSize) и из-за этого у вас все плывёт.

Comment: @Иван верно, это единственный вариант сделать позиционирование стабильным